# Id is not been auto increment id in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL on localhost. I have created a table name students. I have set id as **NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT unique**. But if I add data in table, I have to mention id in the data too. If I don't mention id, an error shows. Following is the code I used to create table.

```
CREATE TABLE students 
(
      id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT unique,
      name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
      email VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL unique,
      age tinyint NOT NULL,
      password VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
      phone_number VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL unique,
      address text,
      gender enum ("M", "F", "O"),
      status boolean default 1
    )
```

In the table, I am adding following data

```
INSERT INTO students
VALUES 
("Liam", "liam@example.com", 20, 123456789, 987654321, "330 Toy Flat Suite 210", "M"),
("Noah", "noah@example.com", 25, 234567891, 876543219, "1240 Dooley Shoals", "M"),
("Oliver", "oliver@gmail.com", 20, 345678912, 765432198, "922 Elody Neck", "F"),
("Elijah", "elijah@gmail.com", 25, 456789123, 654321987, "1704 Mertie Gardens Suite 328", "F"),
("James", "james@google.com", 30, 567891234, 543219876, "46388 Herman Crossing", "F"),
("William", "william@google.com", 30, 678912345, 432198765, "7259 Hubert Mission Suite 338", "F"),
("Benjamin", "benjamin@example.com", 31, 789123456, 321987654, "57126 Ramiro Summit", "M")
```

If I run this code, an error shows.

Even if I add column name "(name, email, age, password, phone_number, address, gender)" before value.

Data do not enter in the table. But if I mention Id, at first, mysql saves the data.

Comment: You have to pass `null` as the value of the `id` column to make it use the auto increment ID.

Comment: The table has 9 columns, you're only providing 7 values. You're also missing `status`.

Comment: I'm not sure, but as I know, you have to make ID as a primary key to make it incremeantable, `PRIMARY KEY (id)`.

Comment: Please include the error messages in the question.

Comment: @NawafKhalifah It has to be index, but doesn't have to be the PK. He has `unique` in the declaration, which is an index.

Comment: @Barmar The status is default 1. So I don't need to mention status. But I don't want to add Id. I want Id to be added automatically.

Comment: you should always specify the columns explicitly.   please show your insert with the column names and the error you get.

Answer (score 3):

When you're inserting, you have to either specify the list of columns you're giving values to, or provide values for all columns. It's best to have an explicit list of columns, so you're not dependent on the order in the table definition. This also allows you to leave out columns that should get defaults.

```
INSERT INTO students (name, email, age, password, phone_number, address, gender) VALUES
("Liam", "liam@example.com", 20, '123456789', '987654321', "330 Toy Flat Suite 210", "M"),
("Noah", "noah@example.com", 25, '234567891', '876543219', "1240 Dooley Shoals", "M"),
("Oliver", "oliver@gmail.com", 20, '345678912', '765432198', "922 Elody Neck", "F"),
("Elijah", "elijah@gmail.com", 25, '456789123', '654321987', "1704 Mertie Gardens Suite 328", "F"),
("James", "james@google.com", 30, '567891234', '543219876', "46388 Herman Crossing", "F"),
("William", "william@google.com", 30, '678912345', '432198765', "7259 Hubert Mission Suite 338", "F"),
("Benjamin", "benjamin@example.com", 31, '789123456', '321987654', "57126 Ramiro Summit", "M");
```

If you don't list the column names, you have to provide values for all columns, **even the ones that have default values**. You can use `NULL` for the auto increment ID column and it will get the incremented values. You can use the keyword `DEFAULT` for columns like `status`, so they get their default value.